# Ambiguous tag: native-client

Tags: support, stack-overflow, ambiguous-tags

[native-client](/questions/tagged/native-client) is ambiguous, it refers to both [sql-server-native-client](/questions/tagged/sql-server-native-client) and [google-nativeclient](/questions/tagged/google-nativeclient).

There are only 13 questions using this tag, so it should be easy to split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Done.** Since there were only 13 questions affected and a decision had to be made about which native client they were talking about, I went ahead and did this myself.

As suggested, all questions regarding Google's Native Client were retagged to [google-nativeclient](/questions/tagged/google-nativeclient), while all of those about SQL Server's Native Client were retagged to [sql-server-native-client](/questions/tagged/sql-server-native-client).

There are still some of the Google questions that use both [google-nativeclient](/questions/tagged/google-nativeclient) and [google-nacl](/questions/tagged/google-nacl), and some that have only one tag without the other. I left those alone, instead supporting [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122858/merge-google-nacl-into-google-nativeclient) since that will be automatically taken care of when the tag synonym is created by a moderator. There's no risk of ambiguity there: all questions with either or both of those tags are clearly talking about Google's Native Client.