# Merge [google-nacl] into [google-nativeclient]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

Merge [google-nacl](/questions/tagged/google-nacl) into [google-nativeclient](/questions/tagged/google-nativeclient).

Google tends to write it out, so we should too.

For example they don't use the NaCl abbreviation on their SDK page at all: https://developers.google.com/native-client/

Comment: But I like salt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I, with the help of a "friend", took the liberty of retagging the remaining 66 questions with the tags. In fact, troggy told me really liked this meal, saying it was quite salty!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree. They are obviously the same thing and it is spelt out more often than not. See code site...

http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [google-nacl](/questions/tagged/google-nacl) tag should be merged into [google-nativeclient](/questions/tagged/google-nativeclient), because the user can't even understand what the meaning of 'nacl'!

The first time I saw this tag, I read it as *google sodium chloride*, but that's not what it is, is it?

Please, let's merge it and minimize the ambiguity to users, and enhance the user experience on the site.

Comment: Er… just read the tag wiki?

Comment: The misspellings of "enhance" and "can't" specifically @Richard. I'm sorry, I didn't actually mean to uncheck that box as it was a really good edit. I do it as a matter of course on SO whenever I have to correct words that are underlined in red and muscle memory seems to have taken over..